# How to switch between fragments using buttons?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an activity with a Viewpager and two buttons inside.
The two buttons are "next" and "back".
I made some Fragment layouts and now want to change the shown Fragment by clicking one of those buttons.

I just know how to use the FragmentStatePagerAdapter to slide between fragments, but how can I do this via onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YourBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //what you want to do 
            Yourpager.setCurrentItem( page )
        }
    });
```